# awk not behaving with qsub

Tags: awk, qsub

I am trying to run a command which is something like this

```
intersectBed -a yeast.v2.bed -b cov.txt -wa -wb | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $7,$8,$9,$6,$11,$10}' > out.txt
```

out.txt looks like this

```
chrI    151006  151096  0
chrI    142253  142619  53
chrI    87387   87500   8
```

I am working on the cluster and when I qsub the above command(that is submitting to the cluster) I get the out.txt file like this

```
chrIt151006t151096t0
chrIt142253t142619t53
chrIt87387t87500t8
```

The command line I am using with qsub is this:

```
qsub -l h_vmem=4G -cwd -j y -b y -N test "intersectBed -a yeast.v2.bed -b cov.txt -wa -wb | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print \$7,\$8,\$9,\$6,\$11,\$10}' > out.txt"
```

As you can see I have to escape each column($) with back slash so that shell does not consider it as its on variable. But some how tab does not work. Can anyone tell me what is going on here. Of course I can use `sed 's/t/\t/g'` after the awk command but I need to understand what is going on here and why does it not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to escape the inner double quotes for `-v OFS="\t"` (or use single quotes instead). SE syntax highlighting gives you a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing:

```
 qsub ... "intersectBed  ... -v OFS="\t"...more double-quoted text"
```

So that `\t` is outside the double quotes. For the shell, outside of quotes, `\` is another quoting operator. There `\t` is like `'t'` or `"t"`, so just `t`.

You're actually doing `awk -v OFS=t`.

Use:

```
 qsub... "inter... | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print \$7,\$8,\$9,\$6,\$11,\$10}' > out.txt"
```

Or, to worry only about single-quote characters:

```
 qsub... 'inter... | awk -v OFS="\t" '\''{print $7,$8,$9,$6,$11,$10}'\'' > out.txt'
```

`set -x` is your friend to investigate this kind of quoting issue.

Comment: Hi Stepahane, that worked pretty well. Where should I put set -x so as to see quoting issue and what will it output. Thanks for the help

Comment: Also when I use $7,$8,$9 in awk on command line it is fine but with qsub I have to escape it, but isn't it is still inside awk quotes??

Comment: @user3138373, in `qsub  ... "inter...'...$1...'..."`, `$1` (and `'`) is inside double-quotes. Shells expand parameters inside double-quotes (`echo "$1"` outputs the content of  the first positional parameter), not inside single quotes (`echo '$1'` outputs `$1`) which is why we don't need the backslash in the second example above).